# Using a client state model object for a hierarchical MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a large hierarchical web application and I need some help deciding on some best practices with leveraging MVC.

The application will have tabs at the top which control a sub page, and a query pane (off to the side).

There will be two templates for query panes, each used by different sub-pages. The sub-pages will be based on the selected tab with settings derived from the query panes.

Clicking on tabs or updating the query pane will update the sub-page section without refreshing the page.

I'm a bit new to MVC and what I don't quite understand is how I can leverage MVC methodologies to help me manage the web application's state (which consists of the selected tab, query options, and other page-specific options).

Currently I'm planning on initially setting up a model which stores the client state parameters (default values, or values obtained from a DB), and using it to load the page, consisting of several partial views. When anything is changed (tab/query/etc), the view will call a corresponding controller, passing back model parameters via post (I'm assuming there's no way to store session-specific client state models on the server-side?).

My question is:

Am I doing it right?
If not, what am I missing; and specifically, is there a way to store these session-specific state models server side so they don't have to be passed back to the server during every single page transaction?

Comment: Be very careful trying to store session-specific data server-side. As many of us have found it can cause issues when people open multiple tabs. e.g. if you store CurrentAccount server-side, and someone opens a new tab and selects a different account, then goes back to the first tab and works on the original account, the operation will likely be done against the wrong account!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood everything you need Its a SPA (Single Page Application). This will provide a magic user experience, without full page reload, and low data traffic. But, requireds some MVVM framework (AngularJS, KnockoutJs, etc) and a lot of JavaScript coding. But the result is amazing. The guy behind this in MVC is John Papa, take a look in everything on his blog and you will win.

[John Papa Blog](http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/)

Hopes Its Help you

Comment: Thank you, I had not considered using MVVM or any related frameworks, but I think this is exactly what I need.